# Facebook graph API, private messages: Difference between threadIds starting with "t_mid." and "t_id."?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a crawler for Facebook private messages on behalf of our customers, which works fine most of the time (99.99%). To answer on these crawled messages I create an url, which corresponds to the "location" of the message. Sometimes the creation of a proper url fails because of a bug in my system. The bug was related to the assumption that a threadId always starts with "t_id." which isn't true. Some threadIds are starting with "t_mid." and I have not the faintest idea why.
My bug is easy to resolve, but my curiosity isn't:

What is the difference between Facebook Ids with these format?

- t_id.############ - ThreadId
- t_mid.############:SomeHexValues - Also ThreadId?
- m_mid.############:SomeHexValues - Unique message id

It seems to be customer related; Most of our customers do have the "t_id" format, only some of them have the "t_mid" format.

I did not find anything related on the documentation at developers.facebook.com, but maybe someone has an idea here.

Answer (score 1):

I use facebook api to read inbox messages and I noticed that the first message always comes with t_mid prefix and the following with m_mid

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to confirm that and mark the answer afterwards as correct